# own process manager based on hydra (mpich)

Tags: process, mpi, mpich

How do you assess the level of difficulty writing own process manager based on the sources of hydra (mpich)? ie., for scale 1 to 100? It will be change the part corresponding to the assignment of processes to computers.

Comment: mpich is not only just a process manager . it is a "message passing interface" which handles communication across these process.

Comment: i know - "(...) on the sources of HYDRA (...)" :)

Answer (score 2):

This shouldn't be too hard, but [Hydra already implements several rank allocation strategies](http://wiki.mcs.anl.gov/mpich2/index.php/Using_the_Hydra_Process_Manager#Process-core_Binding), so you might not even need to write any code.

You can already provide a user-specified rank allocation.  Based on the provided configuration, Hydra can use the [hwloc](http://www.open-mpi.org/projects/hwloc/) library to obtain hardware topology information and bind processes to cores.